# "object not set to instance of an object" when raycast doesn't hit anything

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

The following code produces the error:

```
if (hitInfo.transform.name == "jumppad" && isJumping == false)
```

The error is being given because the raycast is not hitting anything such as a collider, it is just going out into open space.

This is the error that is showing up:

[The error that is showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1iGN.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class gun_script : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform firepoint;

    public LineRenderer linerend;
    public Transform gun;
    public float mouseSens;
    public int jumpHeight = 5;
    float lookangle;
    public Rigidbody2D rbForPlayer;
    Vector2 lookDirection;
    private bool isJumping = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isJumping = false;
        lookDirection = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        lookangle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDirection.y, lookDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        gun.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, lookangle * mouseSens);

        RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(firepoint.position, firepoint.right);

        if (hitInfo)
        {
            linerend.SetPosition(0, firepoint.position);
            linerend.SetPosition(1, hitInfo.point);

        }
        else
        {
            linerend.SetPosition(0, firepoint.position);
            linerend.SetPosition(1, firepoint.position + firepoint.right * 100);
        }

        if (hitInfo.transform.name == "jumppad" && isJumping == false)
        {
            Invoke("Jump", 1f);
        }
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        isJumping = true;
        rbForPlayer.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpHeight));
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check if hitInfo.collider != null.  per documentation *This function returns a RaycastHit object with a reference to the Collider that is hit by the ray (the Collider property of the result will be NULL if nothing was hit)*

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ hitInfo is a struct, thus can never be null.

Comment: `if (hitInfo)` works because the `RaycastHit2D` struct contains `implicit operator bool`. Nevertheless his failing code line is not inside that check.

Comment: @hijinxbassist as mentioned in the comment above in later versions they added an [implicit operator bool](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Modules/Physics2D/ScriptBindings/Physics2D.bindings.cs#L2856) which does exactly that check `return hit.collider != null;` ... but yes according line is simply outside the check so it is executed regardless of a hit or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following null check to check if it hits something.

```
// If it hits something...
if (hitInfo.collider != null)
    ...
```

It is written in [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) of `Physics2D.Raycast`.
See also [the collider property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-collider.html)  of the `RaycastHit2D` struct.

You can also write:

```
if (hitInfo)
    ...
```

At first it looks like that this cannot compile, because `hitInfo` is a `struct` of type `RaycastHit2D` and cannot converted to a `bool`.

But it contains the following code, [see here on GitHub](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Modules/Physics2D/ScriptBindings/Physics2D.bindings.cs#L2856):

```
public static implicit operator bool (RaycastHit2D hit)
{
    return hit.collider != null;
}
```

You already wrote `if (hitInfo)`, but the line causing the error is not included in that check.